# my json file why can't asda print the file?

Tags: json, flutter

i have a json file in the flutter i wrote general code but this code only work for "Hi" and "See you" but i need other question

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dDo9.png)

it looks like this but after the what is cat types it should print the cat types after the "what is cat types" question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.